# Wordpress theme from themeforest for membership website?

Tags: wordpress, themes, membership

I am looking for a theme for forex trading website. Where customer can sign up for paid membership and receive reports daily.

I want a theme which can deal with basic front end design (Company information based home page, about us, contact, blog) and users can signup and login there account. While at back end I can manage accounts and update reports daily.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can be accomplished many different ways, so you'll need to explore what works best for you and your particular skill set. Here's my take in things though.

I would likely go about this with [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and their [StoreFront](https://wordpress.org/themes/storefront/) theme. Storefront is very generic looking out the the box which makes it very customizable. It doesn't have to look like a site that sells t-shirts.

WooCommerce is free and very actively supported. They also off an extension for [paid memberships](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/), which it sounds like you'd be interested in.

I hope this info helps give you some direction.